# unable to start activity componentinfo java.lang.nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I get these errors when i try to run my app on my phone.But does anyone know why im getting these errors? Thanks in advance!
Here are the logcat errors what can be causing these errors?:

```
    01-12 12:35:06.299: D/dalvikvm(12107): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 49% free 2793K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 42ms
    01-12 12:35:06.342: D/dalvikvm(12107): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2792K/5379K, external 2115K/2641K, paused 33ms
    01-12 12:35:09.792: D/dalvikvm(12107): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 48% free 2826K/5379K, external 2449K/2722K, paused 37ms
    01-12 12:38:46.940: W/KeyCharacterMap(12107): Can't open keycharmap file
    01-12 12:38:46.944: W/KeyCharacterMap(12107): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cypress-touchkey.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='cypress-touchkey'
    01-12 12:38:46.944: W/KeyCharacterMap(12107): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    01-12 12:38:58.823: D/dalvikvm(12206): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 48K, 49% free 2793K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 67ms
    01-12 12:38:58.866: D/dalvikvm(12206): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2792K/5379K, external 2115K/2641K, paused 32ms
    01-12 12:39:00.679: D/AndroidRuntime(12206): Shutting down VM
    01-12 12:39:00.679: W/dalvikvm(12206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
    01-12 12:39:00.706: E/AndroidRuntime(12206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-12 12:39:00.706: E/AndroidRuntime(12206): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android.app/android.app.activity3}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: i declared it in manifest  <activity android:name=".activity3"
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                 android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>

Comment: If you added it and are still receiving the error, I suggest appending the contents of your `AndroidManifest.xml` to your question.

Answer (score 5):

```
01-12 12:39:00.706: E/AndroidRuntime(12206): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android.app/android.app.activity3}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Have you declared the `Activity` named `activity3` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` ??

Comment: Wait can someone explain this? I just said i included it in my manifest @willtate

Comment: If you declared the `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and are still receiving the same error, you should edit your question and add your `AndroidManifest.xml` contents.  This will help us help you.

Comment: @user1144349: this was well before you posted that you declared it in your manifest.